# Package mc is not available, but is referred to by another package (i386)

Tags: apt, 32-bit

After upgrade Ubuntu 18.04, to 20.04 can't install Midnight Commander.

Version Linux

```
$ sudo lsb_release -a No LSB modules are available. Distributor
ID: Ubuntu Description: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS Release: 20.04
Codename:   focal
```

source.list

```
deb ----://mirror.yandex.ru/ubuntu/ focal main 
deb ----://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main 
deb ----://mirror.yandex.ru/ubuntu/ focal-updates main 
deb ----://mirror.yandex.ru/ubuntu/ focal universe
```

I try other source, but it's no help

```
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt focal main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt focal main restricted universe multiverse

deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse

deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt focal-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt focal-security main restricted universe multiverse

deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb ----://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner
deb-src ----://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner
```

Update package lists

```
$ sudo apt update 
Hit:1 ----://mirror.yandex.ru/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 ----://mirror.yandex.ru/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease          
Hit:3 ----://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                
Hit:4 ----://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease             
Reading package lists... 
Done Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done 
4 packages can be upgraded. 
Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

Try install mc

```
$ sudo apt install mc 
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree      
Reading state information... Done 
Package mc is not available, but is referred to by another package. This may mean
that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available
from another source However the following packages replace it:  
  mc-data
E: Package 'mc' has no installation candidate
```

Result command dkpg

```
$ dpkg -l mc*
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                    Version           Architecture Description
+++-=======================-=================-============-==========================================================
rc  mc                      3:4.8.19-1        i386         Midnight Commander - a powerful file manager
ii  mc-data                 3:4.8.24-2ubuntu1 all          Midnight Commander - a powerful file manager -- data files
un  mcedit                  <none>            <none>       (no description available)
rc  mcp-account-manager-uoa 3.8.6-0ubuntu9.2  i386         GNOME multi-protocol chat and call client (UOA plugin)
```

I not have idea, how repare it's. May be you have idea?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Comment: Unfortunately, the answer with the restoration of sources did not help. The package 'mc' was still not found.

Comment: Please share the output of the following commands: `grep "^deb\ " -r /etc/apt/ --include=*.list ; sudo apt-get update; apt-cache policy mc` . If long - use pastebin.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/UWFAwZ6g

Comment: Ok, remove all the cached lists by `rm -vrf /var/lib/apt/lists/*` and then retry with `sudo apt-get update; apt-cache policy mc` . Are you using proxy?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/LCkX4EPt
Proxy no use.

Answer (score 0):

I check source in https://mirror.yandex.ru/ubuntu/dists/focal/universe/
and not find package mc in

```
https://mirror.yandex.ru/ubuntu/dists/focal/universe/binary-i386/Packages.gz
```

but find in

```
https://mirror.yandex.ru/ubuntu/dists/focal/universe/binary-amd64/Packages.gz
```

This means that this package is not available for x86 architecture, but is available for x64.

if need install ''mc'', need download from https://launchpad.net

```
cd /tmp/
sudo apt remove mc-data
wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/448485168/mc-data_4.8.23-1_all.deb
wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/448485186/mc_4.8.23-1_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i mc-data_4.8.23-1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i mc_4.8.23-1_i386.deb
```

We can now run ''mc'', but we can not run ''apt full-upgrade'' , because this command install newer ''mc-data'' and removed incompatible with him ''mc''.

Comment: You have to find original root of your problem. I can't reproduce it on fresh 20.04 LTS VM. And please note that http://mirror.yandex.ru/ubuntu/pool/universe/m/mc/mc_4.8.24-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb exits in place. For https://mirror.yandex.ru I see "*E: The repository 'https://mirror.yandex.ru/ubuntu focal-updates Release' no longer has a Release file.*" so it is not secure at all.

Comment: Problem: ''mс''  version 3: 4.8.24 is not present in repositories ''i386''.

Your link leads to the application x64 architecture.

Since the server is not mine, I asked to reinstall Linux x64, becouse x86 is an outdated architecture and problems like this can start to pile up.